# markers vs. marker directive in angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I've got what should be a very, very simple implementation, using the  directive to place a large number of markers on the map. Here is my HTML:

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">
<markers models="allRacers" coords="'self'"></markers>[1]
<marker ng-repeat="r in allRacers" coords="r"></marker>[2]
</google-map>
```

And the relevant bit of my JS:

```
$scope.allRacers = [{
  latitude: 51.51325,
  longitude: -0.174205
}];
```

If I include the line of HTML marked [2], the marker appears, but does not if I include the line marked [1]. To my knowledge these should have exactly the same functionality, and this is a very simple example - is this a bug or am I brain-dead?

I'm using the Bower build of angular-google-maps.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the  directive also requires that an idKey attribute be defined, e.g.:

```
<markers models="allRacers" coords="'self'" idKey="'id'"></markers>
```